# Prove a function is in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

> If $f\in L^2[0,1]$, and $$g(x)=\int_0^1\frac{f(t)\mathrm dt}{|x-t|^{1/2}},\quad x\in[0,1],$$
>   show that $\|g\|_2\le2\sqrt2\|f\|_2$.

I tried [Minkowski's integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality) (with $p=1/2$, so the inequality reverses), but cannot reach the inequality I need. I also used Holder's inequality and failed too.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the domain for $x$?

Comment: @Leg $x\in[0,1]$. I have added it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution steps:

1. Prove that 
   $$
   \int_0^1\frac{1}{|x-t|^{1/2}}\,dt=2\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{1-x}\le 2\sqrt{2}.
   $$
2. Prove that $\|g\|_\infty\le 2\sqrt{2}\|f\|_\infty$ (simple estimation by 1).
3. Prove that $\|g\|_1\le 2\sqrt{2}\|f\|_1$ (using e.g. [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) and 1).
4. Conclude that $\|g\|_2\le 2\sqrt{2}\|f\|_2$ by the [Riesz-Thorin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: How to conclude your step 4?

Comment: @EclipseSun As Steps 2,3 shows the mapping $T\colon f\mapsto g$ is a bonded linear operator from $L^1[0,1]$ to $L^1[0,1]$ and from $L^\infty[0,1]$ to $L^\infty[0,1]$. Then apply the Riesz-Thorin theorem from the link above that gives you the bound $\|T\|_{L^2\to L^2}\le\|T\|_{L^1\to L^1}^{1/2}\|T\|_{L^\infty\to L^\infty}^{1/2}$.

Comment: But we don't know if $\|f\|_\infty$ is finite.

Comment: Oh, I know. Thanks.

Comment: @EclipseSun Perhaps saying "log-convexity of $L^p$ norms" is a bit misleading. I should have said "by Riesz-Thorin theorem" instead from the beginning. Sorry for that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer only uses basic calculus. From the expression of $g$,
\begin{align}
\|g\|_2^2 &=\int_0^1 g(x)^2 dx \cr
& =\int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{|x-t|^{1/2}}\frac{f(s)}{|x-t|^{1/2}}dsdtdx \cr
&\leq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \frac{f(t)^2+f(s)^2}{2}|x-t|^{-1/2}|x-s|^{-1/2}dsdtdx \cr
&=\int_0^1 f(t)^2 \left[\int_0^1 |x-t|^{-1/2}
\left(\int_0^1 |x-s|^{-1/2}ds\right)dx \right]dt. 
\end{align}
Then we can get the desired inequality using the estimate $\int_0^1 |x-s|^{-1/2}ds=\int_0^1 |x-t|^{-1/2}dx\leq 2\sqrt{2}$.

**Comment:** The inequality is actually true for any $L^p$ norm using the interpolation theorem in the other answer.